# AWS KMS - why do I need the "kms:Decrypt" permission when I try to encrypt data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-sqs, amazon-kms

I noticed that in both of the following scenarios:

1. S3 - `PutObject` to an encrypted bucket.
2. SQS - `SendMessage` to an encrypted queue.

I need to have the `kms:Decrypt` permission (in addition to the `kms:GenerateDataKey` permission), otherwise it throws an "unauthorized" exception.

Why would that be the case?

Comment: You mean that `SQS` also requires `kms:Decrypt`? Or `kms:Encrypt`?

Comment: @Marcin I mean `kms:Decrypt`. And it's not the SQS, it's the service who calls the `SendMessage`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From AWS:

> The call to kms:Decrypt is to verify the integrity of the new data key before using it. Therefore, the producer must have the kms:GenerateDataKey and kms:Decrypt permissions for the customer master key (CMK).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html#sqs-what-permissions-for-sse